# read character from file and compare using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, character

I'm only two days old in JavaScript and HTML. I've created a named pipe using a C code and able to write characters into it. The named pipe appears as a file named "xyz". Now I’m trying to read this file using HTML + JavaScript, and access the characters. I want to check for the occurrence of the character 'c' on that named pipe file. 
I'm right now writing to the "xyz" using echo command from terminal of Ubuntu.
I'm able to read the characters and display on the HTML window, but the comparison is not working. 
Following is my code, and inside the "displayContents()" function the statements

```
if('c' == ch)
    el.innerHTML = 'z';
else;
```

is always false even if the file "xyz" has only 'c' as its content.
I'm expecting 'z' as output when the file has 'c', otherwise the content itself on the browser window.
How can it be done and please point out what all things I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Read File (via AJAX)</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
            var el;

            function loadFile() 
            {
                reader.open('get', 'xyz', true); 
                reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
                reader.send(null);
            }

            function displayContents() 
            {
                if(reader.readyState == 4) 
                {                       
                var el = document.getElementById('main');               
                ch = reader.responseText;
                if('c' == ch)
                    el.innerHTML = 'z';
                else;
                    el.innerHTML = ch;
                }
            }

            function delay_ms(delay)
            {
                var now = new Date();
                var desiredTime = new Date().setMilliseconds(now.getMilliseconds() + delay);

                while (now < desiredTime) 
                {
                        now = new Date(); 
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

        <div id="main"></div>

    <body onload = "loadFile();"></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code works as is - I tried to run it and wasn't able to load 'xyz' using XHR. In Chrome, I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/ajhomer/Sites/readfile/xyz. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. index.html:14
Uncaught NetworkError: A network error occurred.
```

But, if you got it to work somehow and are wondering why you never get 'z' as innerHTML, it is because of the semi-colon after else:

```
else;
```

That being said, I made a little example of something that works in chrome.

I assume you are loading the page via the file protocol, something like:

```
file://localhost/Volumes/HD1/Users/user/Sites/readfile/index.html
```

My version uses dynamic script injection instead of XHR, so instead of just writing a single character to 'xyz', you have to write a little javascript that calls 'displayContents', something like:

```
var payload = 'c';
displayContents(payload);
```

Then for the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Read File (via dynamic script injection)</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           function loadFile() 
            {
                var scr = document.createElement('script');
                scr.onload = function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                };
                scr.onerror = function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                var cachebuster = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
                scr.src = 'xyz.js?cb='+cachebuster;
                document.head.appendChild(scr);
            }

           function displayContents(ch) 
            {
                var el = document.getElementById('main'); 
                if('c' == ch)
                    el.innerHTML = 'z';
                else
                    el.innerHTML = ch;
            }

        </script>
    </head>

        <div id="main"></div>

    <body onload = "loadFile();"></body>
</html>
```

This can be done more elegantly - this was just a quick POC.

Comment: Please tell me where are you initializing that variable "ch" before comparing it with 'c'.

Comment: When 'xyz' is loaded, the script is evaluated and displayContents is called, with payload passed as the only parameter.  ch will get whatever payload is set to: in the example I had set it to 'c'.  Let me know if you need more clarification.